# How does the 27 character wide search box recommended length apply to Asian languages and Russian?

Tags: usability, search, user-research

I work for a multinational company. We have a global site, and individual country sites. I am trying to set a width for the search box that will accommodate all of our sites and languages. We've got Japanese, Taiwanese, Thai, Chinese, Korean, and Russian to contend with, as well as several European languages.

Based on [this article](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/top-ten-guidelines-for-homepage-usability/) by NNG:

> Search is an important part of any big website. When users want to
>   search, they typically scan the homepage looking for "the little box
>   where I can type," so your search should be a box. [Make your search
>   box at least 25 characters wide,] so it can accommodate multiple words
>   without obscuring parts of the user's query.
>
> **(Update: Based on more recent findings, my recommendation is now to
>   make the search box 27 characters wide.** This and other new guidelines
>   are covered in our course on Top Web UX Design Guidelines at the
>   annual UX Conference).

Does anyone know if this 27 character width recommendation is global, or are there different width suggestions for languages that don't use Roman lettering?

Comment: @Mo'ath Is say it’s not a duplicate though possibly helpful, OP mentions the 27 character limit suggestion so they likely read that question or the article linked, but they’re specifically asking if it applies to other languages since the character sizes would be different.

Comment: Correct. It is my mistake. I actually was about to delete the comment and add an answer regarding accommodating different languages and still link the question in my comment above.

Comment: Who recommends the 27-character width? I've never heard of that.

Comment: @KenMohnkern I think the supposed recommendation of 27 Character width came from this article [10 Useful Usability Findings and Guidelines](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/10-useful-usability-findings-and-guidelines/#6-the-ideal-search-box-is-27-characters-wide) that is linked in this question [Is there a recommended size for search boxes?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/89346/is-there-a-recommended-size-for-search-boxes)

Comment: I tried to find the actual study. Item 5 in [this article by Nielsen](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/top-ten-guidelines-for-homepage-usability/) says these findings were presented at a NNGroup conference.

Comment: I saw it, thank you. The more I read the more I find this question more interesting! It could have been much more beneficial if resources and some research findings were added. The OP is a new contributor though.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here, but I did not think it would be helpful to list articles about search box length here, when none of those articles helped answer my question about recommended sizes based languages other than English.I did a search here for answers to this question before asking my questions. Mo'ath mentioned adding an answer regarding accommodating dif. languages which would be helpful, but I don't see his answer to my question. Sorry if I did something wrong.

Comment: @OliveLankin You did nothing wrong. Thank you for your question. It is actually a very interesting one and I am reading a lot to learn how to answer it. Can you please tell us what kind of a website is it? and how important is the search functionality? Is it a main functionality of the website?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

You can use a dynamic sized (auto-growing) input field. The search box's size would increase in size as needed while user is typing. Please remember that **the initial size should still be sized according to the expected input**. Check this for examples of how dynamic inputs behave:
[Dynamic input field examples](https://css-tricks.com/auto-growing-inputs-textareas/)

### Is the search-box a core/main functionality or not?

**If the search-box is a core functionality:**

You may consider designs like StackExchange, Google, and Amazon. They are
wide enough to accommodate any of the languages provided.

**If the search-box is NOT a core functionality, then you may consider doing the following:**

**1-** Design for the **longest translation**:
Find out the proper length of a search in your website in English, then
TRANSLATE that to the LONGEST translation of the languages provided. Design
your search-box width with consideration to that translation.

**2-** You may adopt the 27-char search-box width rule (*I am not sure if this rule studied different languages or English only*).

**See examples:**

For websites like StackExchange, Amazon and Google. **Search** is a vital **main** functionality for these websites, hence it is placed in the middle of the main page and it is a **wide** search box.

**Compare that** to Samsung website for example, where Search is **not a main** functionality, it is placed on the side and has just a reasonable width.

<sub>**StackExchange**</sub>
[image: StackExchange]

.

<sub>**Samsung**</sub>
[image]

.

---

**Very useful reads:**

I am providing several resources that I found very useful, not just to help you design a Search-box for different languages/cultures, but also help you UX design the whole website for different languages/cultures.*

**- This article** [Design a Perfect Search Box](https://uxplanet.org/design-a-perfect-search-box-b6baaf9599c) **highlights** the importance of having a **proper size search-box:**

> Making the input field **too short is a common mistake** among
> designers. Of course users can still type long queries in a short
> field, but only a portion of the text will be visible at a time and
> this equates to bad usability, since users cannot review and or edit
> their full query. In fact, when a search box has a limited number of
> visible characters, users tend to use short, imprecise queries, since
> longer queries become inconvenient to read. **If input fields are sized
> according to their expected input they are both easier to read and to
> interpret for users.**

**- This article** [3 things to keep in mind when designing UI to be translated in different languages](https://blog.prototypr.io/3-things-to-keep-in-mind-when-designing-ui-to-be-translated-in-different-languages-e1d02accf21c) discusses how the same message takes different amount of space in different languages and how this difference in the amount of words and characters needed to convey the same message can ruin an interface or make it unusable. See images below:

**English vs Ukrainian**
[image]

**The word "Views" translation ratio:**
[image]

---

**Resources:**

[Design a Perfect Search Box](https://uxplanet.org/design-a-perfect-search-box-b6baaf9599c)

[Best Practice for designing UI for a multilingual site?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/25295/best-practice-for-designing-ui-for-a-multilingual-site)

[Design considerations for internationalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644100/design-considerations-for-internationalization)

[3 things to keep in mind when designing UI to be translated in different languages](https://blog.prototypr.io/3-things-to-keep-in-mind-when-designing-ui-to-be-translated-in-different-languages-e1d02accf21c)

[UX Design Across Different Cultures — Part 1](https://blog.prototypr.io/ux-design-across-different-cultures-part-1-1caa12a504c0)

[UX Design Across Different Cultures — Part 2](https://uxplanet.org/ux-design-across-different-cultures-part-2-761c911e875)

[Is there a recommended size for search boxes?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/89346/is-there-a-recommended-size-for-search-boxes)

Comment: You are welcome @OliveLankin. I actually learned a lot by trying to answer your question. It opened my eyes to issues that I've never dealt with before. If you believe that I answered your question, you may check this from the help center [Help Center - Asking](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I edited it (no change to the answer but I restructured it to make the main points clearer).